# Write Java protobuf class to custom JSON fomat

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

I am trying to find the best approach to print multiple protobuf generated Java classes to a custom human readable JSON format.

Given following code that uses Java class generated from protobuf:

```
Person.Builder personBuilder = PersonData.newBuilder();
Person person = personBuilder
  .setName("John Doe")
  .setAge("99")
  .build();
```

The following is the default JSON representation when using `new JsonFormat().printToString(person)`:

```
{ "name": "John Doe", "age":99 }
```

The desired JSON representation is:

```
"John Doe":{
  "age":99
}
```

Is there a common generic way to achieve the above for multiple protobuf models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by converting from Person object to a Map structure and place the name-value pairs are you choose. 
Natively, the JsonFormat will adhere to the spec https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3 
If you move the name of the person to the name of the object, it might make interoperability harder - depending on what you are trying to do with it of course.